# I am trying to get specific item in a dynamodb list

Tags: asp.net-core, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get specific item from a dynambodb list, below is the table schema

```
{
  "UserId": {
    "N": "0"
  },
  "Messages": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "absoluteTime": {
            "S": "638430874210000000"
          },
          "friendId": {
            "N": "1"
          },
          "messageBody": {
            "S": "Message 1"
          },
          "messageDate": {
            "S": "10/2/2024"
          },
          "messageTime": {
            "S": "20:20"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "M": {
          "absoluteTime": {
            "S": "638430874210000000"
          },
          "friendId": {
            "N": "2"
          },
          "messageBody": {
            "S": "Message 2"
          },
          "messageDate": {
            "S": "10/2/2024"
          },
          "messageTime": {
            "S": "20:20"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am trying to get just a list of `Messages` where `friendId` equals 1.
this is my `queryRequest`

```
          var queryRequest = new QueryRequest
          {
              TableName = tableName,
              KeyConditionExpression = "UserId = :userId",
              ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
              {
                  { ":userId", new AttributeValue { N = userId } },
                  { ":friendId", new AttributeValue { N = "1" } } 
              },
              FilterExpression = "contains(Messages.friendId, :friendId)", 
              ProjectionExpression = "Messages"
          };
```

it does not return anything, I am able to get List of all `Messages` if i just query on `userId` and with loops i can just filter them out. but is there a way to get only list of `Messages` where `friendId` is 1?
This is what i want for the output.

```
  "Messages": {
    "L": [
      {
        "M": {
          "absoluteTime": {
            "S": "638430874210000000"
          },
          "friendId": {
            "N": "1"
          },
          "messageBody": {
            "S": "Message 1"
          },
          "messageDate": {
            "S": "10/2/2024"
          },
          "messageTime": {
            "S": "20:20"
          }
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not possible, unless you know the entire contents of the map that's stored, then you can use contains.

In most cases it's better to store nested maps, as it provides you more flexibility when querying or updating nested objects.

With a list you must either know the position of the object or all of the contents of the object.

Comment: Thanks Leeroy for your answer, So if i want to store these messages i should make a seperate table with user object in it so that i can query on the Id if i do not want to handle them in my code?

Comment: You don't need a second table, you could use the same one if you wish. But the goal is to have an individual item per message. That way you can index on friendId etc...

Comment: I see, thank you for your valuable suggestion.